# How To Concatenate this Sql Column into Single cell?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ClassName    BookCode
First          2
Second         2
Third          2
First          3
Fourth         3
Fifth          3
```

I want to concatenate this into like this :

```
ClassName             BookCode
First,Second,Third       2
First,Fourth,Fifth       3
```

Comment: Go here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
Distinct BookCode,
    (
        SELECT ClassName +','
        FROM table1 t2
        WHERE t2.BookCode= t1.BookCode
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )   Concatenated
    
FROM table1 t1
```

**Output:**

[image]

## [WORKING FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbd5c/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select distinct t1.BookCode,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + t2.ClassName
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.BookCode = t2.BookCode
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,0,',') ClassName
from yourtable t1;
```

NOT TESTED.

Comment: Op for your query _,,Fifth,First,Fourth_

Comment: I did n't test it,is it wrong?

Comment: Not wrong but it's not correct format